# Twitter Bootstrap 2, collapse-nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With Twitter Bootstrap 2, how do get links working within collapse-nav:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="/index.html">Hubsphere - Controller</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="">
            <a href="./index.html">Overview</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have jquery included, and the bootstrap-collapse.js file.

I have tried calling `$('.nav-collapse').collapse()` but this just opens the collapse area and dose not activate the button. which is what i expected as it should just work with markup.

thanks

Comment: I have added bootstrap-collapse.js but it does not seem to help

Comment: Please read the bootstrap documentation thoroughly. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse You're missing the part where you actually call the function $(".collapse").collapse() note that you also need to have jQUery included on the page as well.

Comment: thanks for pointing out about reading the documentation, i did and better the code. If you read the code and the documentation there is a markup option, that should work without having to call the  $(".collapse").collapse(), which in this case is wrong because it would need to be .nav-collapse. from the bootstrap site you will see that they do not call that anywhere. and if you do call it it will just open the collapse that you call it on! did you not read the question it shows a navbar fixed to the top...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was a bit curious to see if this problem still occurs with bootstrap 2.0.4

In fact, it makes no sense to include both bootstrap.js and bootstrap-collapse.js since bootstrap.js includes bootstrap-collapse.js

**only boostrap-collapse.js**
http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/YWUmb/6/

It works pefectly fine as expected.

**both boostrap.js & boostrap-collapse.js:**
http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/YWUmb/5/

If you click on the collapse button for the first time, the div opens and closes immediately. (I think it's because the plugin is declared twice).

And then it works ok.

This issue is specific to the early version of twitter boostrap (2.0.0) but it has been dealt with or no longer occuring due to a change in the plugin structure.

Answer (score 11):

Ok so my problem was that i was including bootstrap.js and the bootstrap-collapse.js in the same file, i assumed that bootstrap.js was needed, and then when it did not work i included bootstrap-collapse.js.

It is now obvious to me, but bootstrap.js is all the bootstrap js rolled up. Which is nice...

Comment: Dang!! I've wasted 2 to 3 hours on this problem!!! I checked and I had the same mess going on as you mentioned.... I had both files. Only need the main one. They should make that more clear. Thank you!!!

Comment: yes it was very annoying, and you kick yourself when you work it out... glad my time help in the end

Comment: I have bootstrap.js and no bootstrap-collapse.js and the menu opens as expected at small widths for IE. Firefox, and mobile Safari, but not for chrome.

Answer (score 3):

There is another case where the bootstrap.css file is required AFTER the bootstrap-responsive.css. That will also cause the button to not appear. Make sure to require the bootstrap.css first BEFORE the bootstrap-responsive.css.

Answer (score 0):

Either you include full bootstrap jquery library (which stores all js to all plugins) or you include single library.

So for ex: if you want to use tooltips you can:

- include: js/bootstrap.js (contains all plugins)

or

- include: bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js

the second method is better because you dont load to a browser things that wont be used!

Use the LESS version from github or compile your own through the bootstrap website custom compiler, never use the default!